# SQL Server : how would I do a truncate and copy in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, truncate, bulk

I'm starting a new project. The task is to basically move data from a file to a database.
Let's say there's one data-file per hour and a line of the file transforms into one row of the database.

Technical Details:

- File-Lines (Entries in DB): 10k - 100k
- Entry: 10 x char[100]

My problem is the updating process.

What I'd like to do is:

**Solution 1:**

1. Leave the actual datatable in tact (original_table)
2. Move the data from the file to a shadow table (copy_table)
3. When the process is done:
4. Truncate `original_table`
5. Bulk copy the data from `copy_table` to `original_table`

**Solution 2:**

1. Add new records to the `original_table`
2. Delete all records with an old timestamp
3. Reorganize `original_table` (shrink, reset index)

**Questions:**

1. Which solution is more efficient?
2. Does someone have a better solution for this problem?
3. How would I accomplish step 4/5 from solution 1 and step 3 from solution 2 in C# (with Entity Framework if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 2 definitely sounds more efficient.  Solution 1 sounds needlessly roundabout.

To accomplish steps 4 & 5 from solution 1 or step 3 from solution 2, just use [`EntityCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitycommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the appropriate T-SQL text - e.g. `TRUNCATE TABLE original_table`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

1. Truncate original_table
2. Add new records to original_table

all wrapped in a transaction?  That way if your copy fails the truncate is rolled back and you don't lose your original table.  No data shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: BAD. It has timing issues in which the table is not accessible which means that other programs must handle this.

Solution 2: Same.

What about:

3: Load the new data into a temporary table, then merge it into the original table.